# returning output parameter from Oracle stored proc

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, output-parameter

I am trying to set the value of the output parameter thirdPartyId, but I am getting an error saying `missing or invalid option` at the `set thirdPartyId` statement.

```
PROCEDURE usp_insert_user(  userType VARCHAR2,
                                logonId VARCHAR2,
                                title VARCHAR2,
                                firstName VARCHAR2,
                                middleName VARCHAR2,
                                lastName VARCHAR2,
                                comments VARCHAR2,
                                thirdPartyId OUT number) AS
      begin
        set thirdPartyId := select max(third_party_id) + 1 from third_party_user_temp;
        insert into THIRD_PARTY_USER_TEMP
            (Third_party_id,web_logon_id,prsn_type_cd,prsn_title_nm,
            prsn_first_nm,prsn_mdl_nm,prsn_last_nm,addtnl_third_party_txt)
            VALUES(thirdPartyId,logonId,upper(userType),title,
            firstName,middleName,lastName,comments)
        ;
    end usp_insert_user;
```

What is the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Update: Is this any safer?

```
insert into THIRD_PARTY_USER_TEMP
        (Third_party_id,web_logon_id,prsn_type_cd,prsn_title_nm,
        prsn_first_nm,prsn_mdl_nm,prsn_last_nm,addtnl_third_party_txt)
        VALUES((select max(third_party_id) + 1 from third_party_user_temp),logonId,upper(userType),title,
        firstName,middleName,lastName,comments)
        returning third_party_id into thirdPartyId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
select max(third_party_id) + 1 into thirdPartyId from third_party_user_temp;
```

This may be subject to contention problems if two people can run this at the same time - both could end up with the same new `thirdPartyId`. You can look at sequences to avoid this.

---

If you define a sequence called, say, `thirdPartyIdSeq`, you can do this:

```
PROCEDURE usp_insert_user(  userType VARCHAR2,
                                logonId VARCHAR2,
                                title VARCHAR2,
                                firstName VARCHAR2,
                                middleName VARCHAR2,
                                lastName VARCHAR2,
                                comments VARCHAR2,
                                thirdPartyId OUT number) AS
      begin
        insert into THIRD_PARTY_USER_TEMP
            (Third_party_id,web_logon_id,prsn_type_cd,prsn_title_nm,
            prsn_first_nm,prsn_mdl_nm,prsn_last_nm,addtnl_third_party_txt)
            VALUES(third_party_id_seq.nextval,logonId,upper(userType),title,
            firstName,middleName,lastName,comments)
        returning third_party_id into thirdPartyId;
    end usp_insert_user;
```

This uses the sequence to generate the next ID, and the `returning` clause populates your OUT parameter.

You can also avoid the procedure and do the ID generation in a trigger, again using the sequence. There are a lot of examples of this approach around, not least on this site.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER third_party_user_temp_bi
BEFORE INSERT ON third_party_user_temp
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT thirdPartyIdSeq.NEXTVAL
    INTO   :new.third_party_id
    FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Your insert then doesn't need to specify the ID to be used.

Comment: is there a way that I can lock the table at the beginning of the stored proc and unlock it at the end to avoid this? I think even if I used a indentity of some sort for the id I would have to return the new ID and I could run into the same issue, where if two people inserted a record and then it returned the id for both they would get the same id...

Comment: Explicit locking probably isn't something you want to dive into. Sequences are the way to go with this.

Comment: sequences are oracles version of identities?

Comment: As far as I understand what you mean by identities, then sort of. Oracle doesn't have auto-incrementing IDs for column values built in. A sequence is a counter that increments and won't return the same value to two sessions, so it can be used to generate the equivalent of an auto-incrementing ID, but requires a bit of code (usually in a trigger) to assign the next value to a column.

Comment: Oracle makes me sad :(. Anyways, I'm updating my question. is the new way any safer?

Comment: haha, did I update my question and you update your answer with the same idea at the same time? Well sorta the same idea with using the returning clause...

Comment: OK. so i created a seq. Now if i enter a bunch of records without using the seq, and then go to use the seq when I execute this stored proc, is the seq going to know that I inserted the other records? Or am I going to be recieving a number that could already be in the table?

Comment: Your update, using the returning clause but still with the max+1 calculation, is not any safer, no. It has the same potential race condition from two users executing at the same moment. (Well, I suppose you might have very slightly reduced the amount of time the contention may exist, but that's not going to be much comfort when it does finally break).

Comment: No, the sequence won't automatically adjust itself if you enter records manually without using it. This is why doing it in a trigger is better, particularly if there's more than one way to insert a record. As long as the trigger is enabled this can't happen.

Comment: O.K. thanks for this information, you have been very helpful!

Comment: Updated with a sample trigger to do this.

Comment: Hi, sequence and a before insert trigger should be your aproach.[http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html](http://jen.fluxcapacitor.net/geek/autoincr.html)

Comment: What if I had the situation where the primary key of a second table was the third_party_id and third_party_seq_no. Where third_party_seq_no was the number of third_party_id records there was in the table. so there would be records like (1,1);(1,2);(1,3);(2,1);(3,1);(4,1);(4,2)... how do i safly determine the value of the third_party_seq_no?